# IBM Rational Application Developer Version 8.5 error

Tags: java, ibm-rational

[IBM ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xi6rD.png)

Error during "complete" phase:
Eclipse p2 reconciler returned with error status=1, check for possible logs in C:\IBM\SDP\configuration for more information.

Comment: Can you give more information or put screenshot ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGelj.png

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is something wrong with your **eclipse.ini** configuration.

Please perform following steps:

1. Go to the folder: ***C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP_1\eclipse.ini*** where **eclipse.ini** file resides.
2. Take back up of your **eclipse.ini** file.
3. Now open **eclipse.ini** in Notepad or Notepad++.
4. Now start removing one property from bottom and check if it works.
5. For example remove last line  **-jar C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP_1\plugins/..** and save the file and start eclipse and see whether it works. Repeat the same steps for other properties.
6. I am telling you to do this because I am not sure which property is misconfigured. So you have to do trial and error part.(Sorry for that).

I hope this may direct you to some solution.

Comment: -vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP_1\jdk\jre\bin\javaw.exe
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
-install
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP_1
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.2.R36x_v20101222
-vmargs
-Dsdp.driver=RADO85-I20120529_2348
-Xquickstart
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
-Xmnx64m
-Xgcpolicy:gencon
-Xscmx48m
-Xshareclasses:name=IBMSDP_%u
-Xnolinenumbers
-XX:MaxPermSize=128M
-Dcom.ibm.ws.management.event.max_polling_interval=1000
-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true

Comment: @user2447500 - can you explain what you are trying to say? It worked?